# CodeIgniter REST API Basic Authentication not working

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I am trying to integrate REST services on my site. I am using this https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver example. So far I was able to successfully call the required data. However, when I wanted to add authorization to it and when I try to access it from Postman I get this error:

```
{
  "status": false,
  "error": "Unauthorized"
}
```

If I remove the auth, it works again. Does anyone know if this is a bug or is there something I'm missing?? This is my configuration:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| REST Login
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Set to specify the REST API requires to be logged in
|
| FALSE     No login required
| 'basic'   Unsecured login
| 'digest'  More secured login
| 'session' Check for a PHP session variable. See 'auth_source' to set the
|           authorization key
|
*/
$config['rest_auth'] = 'basic';

|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| REST Login Usernames
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Array of usernames and passwords for login, if ldap is configured this is ignored
|
*/
$config['rest_valid_logins'] = ['admin' => '1234'];
```

I can't access it through the url as well. The authentication popup keeps appearing even though I have entered the credentials. Please help

Comment: Did you check the "Array of usernames and passwords for login, if ldap is configured this is ignored" ?

Comment: I have removed ldap when setting it up

Answer (score 7):

I struggled with this and I managed to get it working by appending the following to my .htaccess (after the index.php bit):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

In your situation I'm suspecting that the headers don't make it, this will ensure they do.

Answer (score 1):

It is checking for username and password from PHP Server variables

```
$username = $this->input->server('PHP_AUTH_USER'); and 

$password = $this->input->server('PHP_AUTH_PW');
```

In `application/libraries/REST_Controller.php` Line:1971

```
protected function _prepare_basic_auth()
    {
        // If whitelist is enabled it has the first chance to kick them out
        if ($this->config->item('rest_ip_whitelist_enabled'))
        {
            $this->_check_whitelist_auth();
        }
        // Returns NULL if the SERVER variables PHP_AUTH_USER and HTTP_AUTHENTICATION don't exist
        $username = $this->input->server('PHP_AUTH_USER');
        $http_auth = $this->input->server('HTTP_AUTHENTICATION');
        $password = NULL;
        if ($username !== NULL)
        {
            $password = $this->input->server('PHP_AUTH_PW');
        }
        elseif ($http_auth !== NULL)
        {
            // If the authentication header is set as basic, then extract the username and password from
            // HTTP_AUTHORIZATION e.g. my_username:my_password. This is passed in the .htaccess file
            if (strpos(strtolower($http_auth), 'basic') === 0)
            {
                // Search online for HTTP_AUTHORIZATION workaround to explain what this is doing
                list($username, $password) = explode(':', base64_decode(substr($this->input->server('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'), 6)));
            }
        }
        // Check if the user is logged into the system
        if ($this->_check_login($username, $password) === FALSE)
        {
            $this->_force_login();
        }
    }
```

You can configure `PHP_AUTH_USER` and `PHP_AUTH_PW Server` variable as configured in API configuration to authenticate and solve this error or you can use API keys as alternative authentication method.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying! Unfortunately it still doesn't work even with this addition. The same error is there.

Comment: You can  set server vars as `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = 'admin';` and verify by `echo $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];`  similar for password. Also you can set `$config['rest_auth'] = false;` if you dont want to use this basic auth and you can use API key for auth purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out what the issue was! Turns out my server api was fastcgi and so the solution was to change the REST_Controller file. I found this link that works for fast cgi users

https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-36015.html

Hope this helps someone!